# ASCII to binary function

Tags: javascript, binary, ascii

How to reverse this function? It creates a 80-bit binary code from the text, I found it on the internet but do not know how to reverse the operation and make the resulting binary code to restore the text.

```
var ascii2bin = function(ascii)
{
    var bin = "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
    for (var i = 0; i < ascii.length; i++)
    {
        var code = ascii.charCodeAt(i);
        bin += ('00000000' + code.toString(2)).slice(-8);
    }
    return bin.slice(-10 * 8).split('').reverse();
}
```

Comment: You're likely looking for [`parseInt(..., 2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to read in the binary octets as char code values, and then [`String.fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) to turn the char code values into characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function truncates the result to ten characters worth of information (see the `-10` in the last line), so only inputs of less than that length can be reversed:

```
var bin2ascii = function(bin) {
    return bin.reverse().join('').match(/.{8}/g).map(
      x => String.fromCharCode(parseInt(x, 2))
    ).join('');
}
```

Tests:

```
bin2ascii( ascii2bin( '' ) ); // ''
bin2ascii( ascii2bin( 'foo bar' ) ); // 'foo bar'
bin2ascii( ascii2bin( 'Test 123' ) ); // 'Test 123'
bin2ascii( ascii2bin( 'This is a long string' ) ); // 'ong string'
```